# drop down menu from databse no result

Tags: php, html, mysql

im trying to get the value from the database and display them in a dropdown menu
but im getting nothing in the drop down menu, here's the code please anyone ?

```
<select name="car" value="Select" size="1">

<?php
$sql = "SELECT fullname FROM users"; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {
            $name=$row['fullname']; 
            $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$name\">";
    }

?>

<option>
<? echo $options ?>
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you should review your code thoroughly before you want any explanation. You made very silly mistakes what someone wouldn't do who has a basic knowledge of html select tag. there are plenty of beginner tutorials available about pulling data form db and showing in a select box.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code. Try this instead:

```
<select name="car" value="Select" size="1">

<?php
$sql = "SELECT fullname FROM users"; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
            //securing from XSS
            $name= htmlentities($row['fullname']); 

            //you had no closing tag, no name
            $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$name\">$name</option>";
    }
    //need semicolon, no need for tags
    echo $options;
?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean

```
<select name="car" value="Select" size="1">
<? echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

also **$options** should be of the following form:

```
$options .= '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
```

Comment: and you used <? ?> but you used <?php ?> before. Stick with one syntax for god's sake.

Answer (score 0):

```
in your code Semicolon(;) is missing in the end of $options:

<option>
<? echo $options ?>
</option>

also remove `value="Select"` with select tag

try this:

<select name="car" size="1">

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT fullname FROM users";     
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {
            $name=$row['fullname']; 
           echo "<OPTION VALUE='$name'>$options</option>";
    }

?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed option full syntax  `$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$name\">";`
should be  `$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$name\">$name</OPTION>";`

EDIT

```
<option><!--< not required as you already used in $options-->
<? echo $options ?>
</option><!--< not required as you already used in $options-->
```

Answer (score 0):

change ur code to this..

```
<select name='cars'> <?php $sql = "SELECT fullname FROM users"; 

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
        echo "<OPTION VALUE='".$row['fullname']."'>".$row['fullname']."</OPTION>";
}?></select>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have entry in you table just remove extra option from your code

```
<select name="car" value="Select" size="1">

<?php
$sql = "SELECT fullname FROM users"; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {
            $name=$row['fullname']; 
            $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$name\">";
    }

?>
<? echo $options ?>
</option>
</select>
```

just remove `<option>` before  `<? echo $options ?>`

Comment: how can i get the value selected in a variable ? without submitting a form ?

Comment: if youu want to get using jquey use like : var selected_car = $('#Your_car_id option:selected').val(); where #your_car_id = your select box id